# php: use the range output

Tags: php, select, range

I'm new to php.

I want to use the output of the range function.

I've got this already:

```
$var1 = (2);  //depends on input, for example 5  
$var2 = (5);  // depends on input, for example 2  
$number = range($var1+1,$var2-1);    
print_r ($number);
```

This results into this:

```
[0] => 3    
[1] => 4
```

I want two things. Before every output must come a variable. This variable contains one letter. For example the A. the output should be like this:

```
`[0] => A3    
[1] => A4  `
```

After that, I want to comepare the results of my array with the result in my database.

```
/*
$query="select id from stelling where position=\"".$position."\"";  
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);  
$spring = 0;  
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)  
{  
$spring = mysql_result($result, 0);  
}  
*/

if ("$position" == "$number")  
{ 
    echo "done"; 
}
```

I'm stuck in the first part of the code. Right now the print_r of $numbers shows me an array. But when i use the array, it only uses the last generated number. (in the example [1] => 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var1 = (2);  //depends on input, for example 5  
$var2 = (5);  // depends on input, for example 2  
$number = range($var1+1,$var2-1);    
print_r ($number);  

foreach ($number as $key=>$val) {
   $number[$key] = 'A'.$val;
}
print_r ($number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following snipt of code :

```
$var1 = 2;  
$var2 = 5; 
$_char = "A";

foreach (range($var1, $var2) as $number) {
    $_number =  $_char.$number;
   foreach($db_array as $key => $db_number){
      if($_number == $db_number){
       echo "done"; 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = (2);  //depends on input, for example 5  
$var2 = (5);  // depends on input, for example 2  
$number = range($var1+1,$var2-1);  
foreach ($number as $key => $value){
    $number[$key] = 'A'.$value;
}
```

To check if they are the same, use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
if (count(array_diff($position, $number)) === 0){
    echo 'done';
}
```